# How to display fragment *over* tabulation setup as Play Store Settings does?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabs, android-actionbar-compat

My application has **3 main screens** (1 fragment for each) presented in an Action Bar Compat with **NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS**.

From the action bar and the menu, the user will be able to reach for

- settings,
- profile,
- credit card
- etc.

Which are **less used** functionality. So I feel (from android guidelines) that they should not be regrouped inside a 4th tabulation (as they are currently).

How to display the less-used fragments with a similar feeling to the way Google Play creates and displays its screen Settings (leaving the tabs mode)? Do I need a secondary activity? Can I stay in the same activity (best case for me) and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second Activity, where you can show your other fragments. You can put a flag in the Intent, which you need for the startActivity() method, so you can check which fragment should be shown in your OtherActivity. For the up navigation you need to edit your manifest like this, to set activity hirarchy:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.OtherActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.test.ActivityMain" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.test.ActivityMain" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

You also have to add this line code to the onCreate() method in your OtherActivity to see the up navigation button:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Otherwise can stay in your activity, replace your fragment and hide() the Actionbar, but the hide() animation looks a little bit strange. Besides you won't have a up button and it's not the best practice.

Comment: Thank you, it enlightens well what to do for a secondary activity.  
For the record, I think it is important to distinguish between the UP button and the BACK button. 
As I wrote,  I don't want to hide the action bar, only to quit the tabs mode.

Comment: You are right...I corrected my answer by replacing the back with up button. If my answer helped you out, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I like to let time before accepting an answer in case someone else might be willing to add information... I talk with another guy and he concurs that a secondary activity is a good design principle to separate the application "job" from "settings".